# Repurposing unused desktop as server for data processing

Tags: remote, remote-access, fortran

I have two computers. One is a 2010 MacBook (the white polycarbonate one!). It's a very capable laptop, since I installed an SSD and upgraded the RAM. It does everything I need on a daily basis, but recently it's started to feel a little slow for my purposes. I have been writing some Fortran programs that will result in calculation-heavy simulations. For data visualization, I have also needed to write some R scripts that generate hundreds of frames (for a posterior animation). Therefore, the only thing I can do with this computer are little test runs with toy datasets just to check that everything works okay. But I have another computer, a somewhat more powerful desktop. It's not an extremely powerful computer by any means, but it does have a good processor, dedicated graphics and more RAM than my laptop.

My question is: is there a way I could use this computer as a remote server for data processing? Can Ubuntu Server be used for this? The type of things I will need to do are:

- Sending uncompiled Fortran code, R scripts, and very light datasets.
- Compiling the code using gfortran, and being able to navigate the file system in the computer to check that everything is where it's supposed to be.
- Run R scripts and send the results (probably around ~1 GB worth of data every time) back to my laptop.

I will be constantly moving (I live/study/work in a different city, and I don't have a fixed address for practical purposes), so once all of this coronavirus thing ends I won't be able to physically access this desktop, but I still will need to run simulations in it.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As a *server*, yes - easily. Simply install Ubuntu Server, set up your router's port forwarding (if needed), install your SSH keys, and get familiar with controlling the machine via ssh.

- Advice: ALWAYS use ssh keys on any internet-facing server.
- Advice: Whenever possible, use an ethernet connection between router and server, not wifi. Wifi drops or interference may make your server connection annoyingly slow or unreliable.

As a *remote server* is more challenging. Remote servers must be reliable, of course, and laptops are not the best hardware platform for always-on reliability.

- Laptops usually require (valuable) desk space with airflow, screen up. They usually cannot be parked in a closet or enclosed shelf without overheating.
- In the event of a power loss, most laptops will NOT automatically reboot upon restoration of power.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I don't know if I explained myself —the laptop is my everyday computer, the one I want to turn into a remote server is a desktop.

Comment: Will your desktop reboot in the event of a power loss? (it's a BIOS setting)